# postgresql error "malformed array literal"

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to insert data into my table,

```sql
INSERT INTO korisnici ("ime","prezime","lokacija")
VALUES ('name','lastname','location')
```

But when i try to execute that i got an error "ERROR: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.malformed array literal: "name" ERROR: malformed array literal: "name" SQL state: 22P02 Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information. Character: 60"

I try to google the error but can't find any respone.

This is how i create table

```sql
CREATE TABLE korisnici (
  ime VARCHAR[30],
  prezime VARCHAR[30],
  location VARCHAR[30]
)
```

Comment: Don't use [ and ], use the ( and ) to create the columns. Using [ and ] creates an array

Comment: Reading the docs [Character types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the syntax you used to define the VARCHAR type for the columns in your CREATE TABLE statement. In PostgreSQL, you should use parentheses () instead of square brackets [] to specify the length of a variable character type.

To correct the issue here is a correct way to write your statement:

```
CREATE TABLE korisnici (
  ime VARCHAR(30),
  prezime VARCHAR(30),
  location VARCHAR(30)
);
```

after using the correct syntax above you can now insert your values and get your desired output.

Comment: it works thank you <3